# UI response is too slow when attach large document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap tab control, That is pretty fine. On each tab i need to load an html document (large may be greater than 10MB). Everything works fine. but after loading data UI response is too slow even it takes 5,6 seconds to switch the tab.
I don't want any delay while clicking. UI should responsive every time.
I there any way to achieve this?
This is what i have done so far...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dpa" data-toggle="tab">DPA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rn" data-toggle="tab">Antwon</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" style="width:100%;height:600px;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="dpa" data-src="../TabsData/data2.htm">
                <iframe src="" style="width:100%;height:600px"></iframe>
                <div id="data"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="rn" data-src="../TabsData/data2.htm">
               <iframe src="" style="width:100%;height:600px"></iframe>
                <div id="data"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Javascript code

```
$('#myTabs').bind('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    paneID = $(e.target).attr('href');
    src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');
    // if the iframe hasn't already been loaded once
    if ($(paneID + " iframe").attr("src") == "") {
       $(paneID + " iframe").attr("src", src);
    }
});
```

NOTE: Okay it should response slow on loading as it has large data to load. But why slow once everything has been loaded?

Comment: You're loading 10Mb of text in to the DOM; it's going to be slow. If you want to speed it up then you need to not load so much data at once. You could use paging or lazy loading to load manageable chunks of data for the user to view before requesting the next chunk when required.

Comment: check also you are not loading every time the user change of a tab the same data again and again

Comment: First i can't use paging, second once it fully loaded, then why its still slow UI  respose?
It should behave normally when file has been fully loaded.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i need the same data again and again.

Comment: why every time changing tab,innerHTML will be set?

Comment: Not every time, will change first time if iframe has not src

Comment: @SirajHussain Outright bad development model .

Comment: I found this video very helpful in understanding the JavaScript event loop, why things get slow or block other operations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 3):

Since you are loading large files on tab change it's better to load them in background before use even makes any actions.

Specify `iframe` source in tag instead of loading it dynamically. This way data will be downloaded even before user clicks on tab.

---

*Side note*
`$(paneID).attr('data-src')` can be changed to proper data attribute usage `$(paneID).data('src')`
`$(paneID)[0].children[0].innerHTML = data` I don't see where you set `data` variable
`$(paneID)[0].children[0].innerHTML = data` can be changed to `jQuery`: `$(paneID).children().eq(0).html(data)`
`$(paneID + " iframe")` can be changed to `var pane = $(paneID); $('iframe', pane)`. Also it's good to cache your element as you are using it in multiple places.

Answer (score 3):

1) Browser processes get slow when they overuse memory, because then the OS doesn't allocate for them more space in the RAM, but instead they have to keep some of the data in the hard-disk, which is a much slower hardware.

2) In your case it's not data but UI, which makes the browser need even more memory and more CPU, because the UI isn't evaluated once but over and over again all the time (this is the reason why when the browser is stuck, you see a blank page).

3) Your page is extremely large. I've never encountered such a large page. I've seen some very long pages, but yours "beats" them because of all the markup.

You have no choice but to hide the UI that the user doesn't see at the moment. It's OK that you bring all the data together, but you still need pagination or any other method for UI hiding.

Answer (score 3):

The thing about Javascript is that it is single-threaded. So when you're trying this large operation, it blocks other browser events until this operation is done. There have been, however, recent developments in Javascript to allow for multi-threaded processes.

**Option 1 - Web Workers**

Looking at and leveraging [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to offset the process so that it doesn't affect the responsiveness of your UI.

**Option 2 - AJAX**

Using AJAX to load in your HTML so that the process is asynchronous. That way, the browser can load in the background without affecting your UI.

```
$("#yourDiv").load("demo_test.html");
```

Both will solve your UI problem as it correctly allocates the browser resource to "another thread".

Answer (score 2):

I created a quick site replicating what you want to achieve. I used the default tab javascript provided by bootstrap. Please see the entire code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dpa" data-toggle="tab">DPA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#rn" data-toggle="tab">Antwon</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" style="width:100%;height:600px;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="dpa">
            <iframe src="1.html" style="width:100%;height:600px"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="rn">
           <iframe src="2.html" style="width:100%;height:600px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

The bootstrap script include all that is needed for the tabs to work, so your own javascript is not needed. The 1.html and 2.html are copies of the data you provided in the comments.

Comment: Any chance you could give an example of the data that is being loaded in?

Comment: I've just thrown that document onto one of my sites and it loaded in under 1 second. Who do you host with if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: That would be great help. I am loading on local host. I dont have rendering problem but once it get loaded. My ui tabs response too slow.

Comment: Just to summarise the new answer. Your own javascript is slowing everything down, included in the bootstrap script is the code for changing tabs, so you don't need to provide it.

Comment: I have tried above code with no script and getting the same result, I don't how its working on your side. In my case it still takes 4,5 seconds to enable next tab click.

Comment: It must be something to do with your hosting, I actually made the site live on one of my sites and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113129/discussion-between-siraj-hussain-and-alex).

Answer (score 2):

There are few things i think will improve your speed

- first minify the html document check this image you will reduce around 2mb
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85ULS.png
- second use ajax method to load the document like $("selector").load("href");

Answer (score 2):

why dont you just gzip the content and also set the expiry headers in your .htaccess file

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## Default directive

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

## My favicon

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

## Images

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

## CSS

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

## Javascript

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent

as it will keep the data in the cache and performace will be good i guess i am not too sure but just give it a try.. normally it happens because of low memory or ram.. to process the dom which take too much process..

Comment: I don't think a good solution is one that uses a backend solution to solve a client-side problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Render Delays

After a page has been loaded some things that are trivial to code can cause dramatic performance implications because of the render cycle, in this case your tabbing API is conducting "layout" changes to your page by hiding and showing the appropriate tab. This requires a complete re-render of the tabs internal html structure, depending on the tabs content it can potentially be quite intensive.

See [Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/?hl=en) for more information on the browsers rendering cycle.